# Experience manager throws 404 error while creating new page

Tags: experience-manager, dxa

I am trying to create new page(Section Page) using XPM with DXA website. The moment I press "Create Page" button I am getting *404 - File or directory not found*. message. I check in the CMS and found page has been created successfully in CME with default content. Please suggest what could be the issue? The url for the xpm page is http://sdltridion.xxxx.xx/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=editing-site&url=%23url%3D%252Fpocarticle.html

Comment: You should provide some more information. Do you see any errors or warnings in the log files of your DXA website or in your session preview odata webservice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan & Will for your inputs. After deeper investigation I have found I missed the entry of staging website url under "Session Preview" tab of Publication Target.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `se_blank.html` file in the root of your site?

This is mentioned on the [Preventing 404 errors on your staging Web site](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A484302D-31DA-474E-B70F-3A98773C38F7) page of the online documentation.

Comment: This is not necessary for DXA - a route for se_blank.html is added on application startup (to the Blank action of the Page controller)

Comment: Thanks @WillPrice - Maybe that info will give Vivek another path to investigate.